# htaccess Redirect-Loop on silex-framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, silex

following problem:
My htaccess generates a redirect-loop.
On my local system there is no problem, but on a web-server (1und.de) i get the redirect loop.

I have the typical structure:
public-directory with .htaccess and index.php.
index.php includes the silex-application (../src/app.php)

This is my .htaccess:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have to define the RewriteBase, otherwise it will not work.
Can anyone help?

This is part of my app.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../config/config.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = false;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'dbname'    => DATABASE,
        'user'      => DATABASE_USER,
        'password'  => DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'port'   => DATABASE_PORT,
    ),
));


$app->get('/', function ()   use ($app) {
    return $app->redirect('/de');
});

$app->get('/de', function ()   use ($app) {
    $data = [];
    $data['currentNews'] = getCurrentNews($app['db']);
    $data['moreNews'] = getMoreNews($app['db'], $data['currentNews']['id']);
    $data['allSeriesWithRaces'] = getAllRaces($app['db']);

    return $app['twig']->render('front/de.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
});

$app->boot();
$app->run();
```

getCurrentNews(), (), getAllRaces() is just fetching some data from database.

Structure:
public_html
- public (Document-Root)
-- index.php (including app.php)
-- .htaccess
- src
-- app.php

Comment: Is your document root set to the public directory?

Comment: Yes, public is my document root.

Comment: Is it looping to `/`, or something else and back again? Mind sharing your `app.php` code?

Comment: It's redirecting to itself.

It's a silex application (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). 
My default-route / is just rendering a template.
The route loops itself.

If the route / redirects to route /de the loop is going to /de and back to index.php

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to help much without seeing some more code. Your `.htaccess` looks fine.

Comment: I edited my question with a part of my app.php

Comment: Not sure you need `$app->boot()`... See what happens when you remove that.

Comment: I removed it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Regarding `public_html` as the Document root, where is your `app.php` file? Please edit your question and add the tree structure of your file hirearchy

Comment: Added the structure to my question.